# How to get ERC20 Token Transaction of a specific contract using Web3py

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3py

I'm using web3py and I want to get the transaction history of a specific contract. Here's my code sample

```
eventSignatureHash = web3.keccak(text='Transfer(address,uint256)').hex()


filter = web3.eth.filter({
    'address': '0x828402Ee788375340A3e36e2Af46CBA11ec2C25e',
    'topics': [eventSignatureHash]
})
```

I'm expected to get ERC20 Token Transactions related to this contract as found [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x828402Ee788375340A3e36e2Af46CBA11ec2C25e#tokentxns) but it does not display anything unfortunately. How to go about this?

Finally, is there a way to watch these transactions in real time?

Answer (score 0):

What i did is that i created a contract instance:
contract = web3.eth.contract(address = contract_address)

then trasnfer_filter = contract.events.Transfer.filter(u have optional parameters such as: fromBlock:...,toBlock, argument_filters:{"to": users_address(this filters for transfers only to that address)})
so you can play around it.

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractEvents

found in the event log object section.

Answer (score 0):

As is answered by other's answer, `contract.events` provides lots of useful methods. If nothing is returned, specifying `from` and `to` might help.

And besides, an ultimate solution is already provided here -> [Advanced example: Fetching all token transfer events](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events).

> Finally, is there a way to watch these transactions in real time?

Actually, lots of nodes support subscribe RPCs. However, this feature is not yet supported by web3py([#1402](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1402)). You can try SDK in other language or temporarily adopt this method [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103925/subscribing-to-new-block-headers-using-python-web3py)